# Error inflating inner class view

Tags: android, view, inflate

I'm trying to inflate an inner class view and getting the "error inflating class" problem.  I've referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml) which was helpful, but I'm still lost as to why I can't get this to work.

Here is a code excerpt, my XML, and logcat.

Edit:  Also I noticed that logcat states a "no such method exception" for "CupcakeMessageView(Context, AttributeSet) when I clearly have it.

THANKS ALL!

```
public class CupcakeMessage extends Activity {

    class CupcakeMessageView extends View {
        private static final int TEXT_SIZE = 12;
        private static final int X_OFFSET = 15;

        private Paint mPaint;   

        public CupcakeMessageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CupcakeMessageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            mContext = context;
            ...
        }

        more class stuff... 
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.cupcake_message); 

        ...      
    }
}
```

Here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <view class="com.cmllc.zcc.CupcakeMessage$CupcakeMessageView"
        android:id="@+id/cupcake_message_view"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    more views...
```

Logcat:

```
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cmllc.zcc/com.cmllc.zcc.CupcakeMessage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.cmllc.zcc.CupcakeMessage$CupcakeMessageView
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.cmllc.zcc.CupcakeMessage$CupcakeMessageView
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:503)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at com.cmllc.zcc.CupcakeMessage.onCreate(CupcakeMessage.java:119)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     ... 11 more
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: CupcakeMessageView(Context,AttributeSet)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:660)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:477)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:475)
12-19 09:31:24.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5435):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: Try making your inner class `public static`

Comment: +1.  That worked.  Care to explain why?

Comment: Declaring public static results in non-reentrant code, and so only works when a single instance of the inner class is required. See (280Z28's answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986603/why-do-nested-classes-in-java-differ-from-nested-classes-in-c-sharp-in-the-follo for the Java-to-CSharp inner-class conversion

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add `public static` to the inner class.

- `public` because it needs to be visible from outside.
- `static` because if not you will need to have `CupcakeMessage` to instantiate it.

All the same I would recommend doing the `View` in a separated class.

Comment: I did put the view in a separate class originally.  I decided to put it as in inner class because the view is basically the whole activity minus a couple buttons.  To me, this implementation is simpler and easier to understand.  Thanks for your help.