# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file

Tags: android, exception, canvas, inflate

I'm getting this strange error in the logcat and I've tried everything that came to my mind to solve it and still getting it.
Here is the logcat:

```
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dm.test/com.dm.test.ui.BitCanvasActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.dm.test.ui.BitCanvasActivity$CanvasView
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.dm.test.ui.BitCanvasActivity$CanvasView
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:508)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1716)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at com.dm.test.ui.BitCanvasActivity.onCreate(BitCanvasActivity.java:55)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     ... 11 more
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: CanvasView(Context,AttributeSet)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)
11-08 12:30:26.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4396):     ... 21 more
```

and this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bitdraw="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.dm.test" >

    <view
    class="com.dm.test.ui.BitCanvasActivity$CanvasView"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

    <com.dm.test.widget.ActionButtons
        android:id="@+id/btn_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />


    <com.dm.test.widget.ColorPicker 
        android:id="@+id/color_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        bitdraw:colors="@array/color_picker_colors"
        bitdraw:cols="3"  
        bitdraw:fils="5" />

</merge>
```

and on the .java line 55 its this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.bit_canvas ); //line 55
    mActionButtons = ( ActionButtons ) findViewById(R.id.btn_actions);
    mColorPicker = ( ColorPicker ) findViewById( R.id.color_picker );
```

and this is part of the inner class:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

    public CanvasView(Context c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CanvasView (Context c, AttributeSet atr, int defstyle){
        super(c, atr,defstyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { ... }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, because I seriously ran out of ideas :S

Comment: You need to declare the inner class static.

See this [answer on stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483433/error-inflating-inner-class-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your layout for the one below, since on that way you will be calling the class item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bitdraw="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.dm.test" >

    <com.dm.test.ui.BitCanvasActivity.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

    <com.dm.test.widget.ActionButtons
        android:id="@+id/btn_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />


    <com.dm.test.widget.ColorPicker 
        android:id="@+id/color_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        bitdraw:colors="@array/color_picker_colors"
        bitdraw:cols="3"  
        bitdraw:fils="5" />

</merge>
```

if that doesn't work try making your class as jordi said.

Answer (score 2):

You need a "handler" to modify the Android interface within a Thread.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html.