# No such method exists

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror

I've been playing around with code I found at [Android Development - Playing with graphics in Android](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html).

Unfortunately, I haven't been so lucky with my implementaion of the code lol I believe, based upon *LogCat*, that Android is unable to find a method which does exist.

Below are the logcat details:

***Logcat***

```
 02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner/com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct$designCanvas
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct$designCanvas
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:508)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct.onCreate(NewProduct.java:28)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284):     ... 11 more
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: designCanvas(Context,AttributeSet)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
    02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)
02-08 12:43:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(9284):     ... 21 more
```

***NewProduct.java***

```
public class NewProduct extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_product);
}

class designCanvas extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private drawThread _thread;
    private ArrayList<GraphicObject> _graphics = new ArrayList<GraphicObject>();

    public designCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new drawThread(getHolder(), this); 
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                GraphicObject graphic = new GraphicObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle_point));
                graphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) event.getX() - graphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
                graphic.getCoordinates().setY((int) event.getY() - graphic.getGraphic().getHeight() / 2);
                _graphics.add(graphic);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    @Override 
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Set canvas background size and colour
        Path mPath = new Path();
        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        

        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        Bitmap productImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.glass_lamp);
        canvas.drawBitmap(productImage, 0, 0, paint);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        paint.setAlpha(255); //0x80
        c.translate(0, 30);
        //c.drawBitmap(productImage, new Matrix(), paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        
        Bitmap bitmap;
        GraphicObject.Coordinates coords;
        for (GraphicObject graphic : _graphics) {
            //Create a graphical point indicating where the user has touched on screen.
            bitmap = graphic.getGraphic();
            coords = graphic.getCoordinates();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.getX(), coords.getY(), null);
            //Create path coords points are being placed on canvas.
            Log.d("Point Cords", String.valueOf(coords.getX() + " " + coords.getY()));
            
            if (_graphics.isEmpty()) {
                //_graphics array has no entries, so this is the first coord.
                mPath.moveTo(coords.getX(), coords.getY());
            } else {
                //Record subsequent coords.
                mPath.lineTo(coords.getX(), coords.getY());
            }
        }
    }
    
    //@Override
     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        //TODO something
    }
    
    //@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();
    }
 
    //@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        } 
    }
}

class drawThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private designCanvas _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;
        
    public drawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, designCanvas panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }
        
    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }
        
    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }
        
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) { 
                    _panel.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class GraphicObject {
    /**
     * Contains the coordinates of the graphic.
     */
    public class Coordinates {
        private int _x = 100;
        private int _y = 0;
 
        public int getX() {
            return _x + _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }
 
        public void setX(int value) {
            _x = value - _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }
 
        public int getY() {
            return _y + _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        }
 
        public void setY(int value) {
            _y = value - _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        }
 
        public String toString() {
            return "Coordinates: (" + _x + "/" + _y + ")";
        }
    }
    
    private Bitmap _bitmap;
    private Coordinates _coordinates;

    public GraphicObject(Bitmap bitmap) {
        _bitmap = bitmap;
        _coordinates = new Coordinates();
    }

    public Bitmap getGraphic() {
        return _bitmap;
    }

    public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        return _coordinates;
    }
}
```

and finally, the **new_product.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<view class="com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct$designCanvas"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

             ... Code snipped ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry for the amount of code above, it just I'm curious as to where I'm wrong.
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483433/error-inflating-inner-class-view

Comment: Did you specify the activity in your manifest.xml?

Comment: Hi sorry for taking a while to reply. @THelper, yes the activity is specified within the manifest.xml file.

Comment: @Sergey I had a look at the link you have suggested. Many thanks for that. I have inserted `public class` before the inner class. In doing so, I had to change `class designCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` to `public designCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`. When I run the app I get the error the same errors as before.

Comment: @Sergey My apologies I should mention that eclipse has underlined two lines of code. Line `_thread = new drawThread(getHolder(), this)` and line `GraphicObject graphic = new GraphicObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle_point));` and the error message is `No enclosing instance of type NewProduct is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type NewProduct (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of NewProduct).`

Comment: I have just tested the activity you pasted I didn't get any errors. The only thing I changed was in xml `<view class=` to `<View class=` because it wasn't allowed there of course. Case sensitive.

Comment: It worked! Many thanks Sergey :) I'll remember .xml is case sensitive now lol would you like to post the answer and I can then tick it was successful?

Comment: I have made a wider explanation to that case in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is there useful post ofcourse 
[Error inflating inner class view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483433/error-inflating-inner-class-view)

and the last thing which helped was to change
in layout xml `<view class=` to `<View class=` 
because the layout XMLs are `case sensitive`.

an excerpt from here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

In general, the XML vocabulary for declaring UI elements closely follows the structure and naming of the classes and methods, **where element names correspond to class names and attribute names correspond to methods**. In fact, the correspondence is often so direct that you can guess what XML attribute corresponds to a class method, or guess what class corresponds to a given xml element. **However, note that not all vocabulary is identical. In some cases, there are slight naming differences.** For example, the EditText element has a text attribute that corresponds to EditText.setText().