# Android Custom Widget Inflate Exception

Tags: android

**XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.org.BatteryManager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >
    <com.org.BatteryManager.BatteryView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:textColor="#ffffffff"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

> 02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.org.BatteryManager.BatteryView
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:930)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:219)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:250)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:73)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.org.BatteryManager.BatteryView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[.]
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
>           02-17 18:49:49.392: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(124):     ... 15 more

Comment: Try removing the @RemoteViews tag if you have one, that worked for me. Was racking my brains to figure this out.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same confusing problem. To fix it your custom view should provide a constructor with two arguments: Context and AttributeSet as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739661/android-error-inflating-class/3739853#3739853).

Comment: Also caused by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml

Answer (score 0):

What is com.org.BatteryManager.BatteryView?

If you want to use a custom view then it is possible. The way to do it is create a custom view class in Java that extends some base view component class.

For example, I use custom Gallery components in lots of my applications. The gallery class will only move one frame left or right on a swipe which is different from the default behavior.

The way that I made my custom gallery is to extends the basic Gallery class --

```
package com.testing.whatever;

public class CustomGallery extends Gallery {
    //CODE OVERRIDES HERE
}
```

Then in my XML code, the code looked similar to what you already have --

```
<com.testing.whatever.CustomGallery android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I suspect you're getting your error because you haven't coded com.org.BatteryManager.BatteryView or it's in the wrong place in your java files.

Comment: This does not work for an app widget. App widgets cannot use custom classes.