# Android How to set an xml shape as widget background?

Tags: android, widget

How can I set a shape defined in xml as background of an image in a widget?
Here are my attempts:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.widgetshape);  //class cast exception
Bitmap bp = ((BitmapDrawable)dr).getBitmap();
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ImageView01, bp);
```

This results in an android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable class cast exception.

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(WidgetConfig.this.getResources(),  R.drawable.widgetshape);
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ImageView01, icon);
```

This throws a NullPointerException error on the `awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);` line.

```
Bitmap bp = ((BitmapDrawable)this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.widgetshape)).getBitmap(); //Class Cast Exception
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ImageView01, bp);
```

This results in an android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable class cast exception on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `setInt` method calling on the `RemoteViews` instance:

```
views.setInt(R.id.layout, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.widgetshape);
```

For this to work, you must have an `@id` attribute set to **`"layout"`** on the `View` (probably the root view) of your widget layout (in xml).

You can also define a background to that View from xml, like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/widgetshape">
```

Comment: What problem do you have? do you happen to have the logcat output to share? Both of the above implementations work just fine for me.

Comment: Logcat says: updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view. I don't understand why does it say that

Comment: please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7299587/506879 and create the necessary constructor(s) to eliminate this problem. Also clean and recompile your project if you have changed any resources: ant often misses the changes.