# Instantiating an inner class (Preference) in xml file

Tags: android, inner-classes, android-xml, preference, preferencescreen

When you want to access a custom view in some `layout.xml` file, you  have two options:

1. The view is in it's own class. Then you do `<package.name.MyView android:layout_width= ... />`
2. The view is an inner class: `<view class="package.name.OuterClass$MyView" android:layout_width= ... />`

**Now I want to do the same thing inside a `<PreferenceScreen>`.** The first way works well, but I would like to put all the custom `Preference` classes together in my PreferenceActivity. I tried `<Preference class="package.name.OuterClass$MyPreference" ... />` (also with '.' instead of '$') as well as `<package.name.OuterClass.MyPreference ... />`, but both failed.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Make sure your inner classes are static.

Comment: Still neither methods work. Strange to say the 'class' attribute is entirely ignored, even if it contains nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with `Views` inflating, `LayoutInflater` looks for a "view" -> "class" case:

```
View createViewFromTag(View parent, String name, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (name.equals("view")) {
        name = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "class");
    } ...
```

Preference's `PreferenceInflater` doesn't, so that is for the "class" case.

It uses reflection in its `createItem()` method and that's probably why the first case works for you.

Comment: This is so aggravating.