# Classcast Exception while dealing with custom imageview

Tags: android

I am working on an application that uses canvas.I  am using a custom imageview. But when I try to run  the application I get an error. The code I have written is as follows

```
private static MyView myimageView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            myimageView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myView);

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            myimageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Intent i = getIntent();     
            loc = i.getFloatArrayExtra("Location");
            myimageView.buildDrawingCache();

            bmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(myimageView.getDrawingCache());
            bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(myimageView.getDrawingCache());


        }


    }

    public static class MyView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener{ // or some other View-based class
           public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

           MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
            }

            MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            }

        boolean drawRectangle = false;
           PointF beginCoordinate;
           PointF endCoordinate;



           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int count=1;

                if(event.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


                     if (count==1){

                         x1 = event.getX();
                         y1 = event.getY();



                         System.out.println(count+"count of value a;skd");

                         Log.i(TAG, "coordinate x1 : "+String.valueOf(x1)+" y1 : "+String.valueOf(y1));
                     }
                }
                     else if(event.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                         invalidate();
                        // imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
                         x2 = event.getX();
                         y2 = event.getY();
                         posX=(float)(x1+x2)/2;
                         posY=(float)(y1+y2)/2;
                         radius=(float) Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2))/2;
                        // onDraw();
                            }
                if(event.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                     {
                    invalidate();
                     // onDraw();
                        //bmp2=bmp;
                         if(action==2)
                         {


                     }
                     }





                return true;

            }

           public void onDraw(){
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(myimageView.getWidth(), myimageView.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                c = new Canvas(bmp);
                myimageView.draw(c);
                Paint pnt = new Paint();
                pnt.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                pnt.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                pnt.setStrokeWidth(3);
            if(action==1)
            {

                c.drawCircle(posX,posY, radius, pnt);
                pnt.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                myimageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                i = 1;
            }else{

                float h=(float) 30.0;

                float phi = (float) Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1); 
                float angle1 = (float) (phi - Math.PI / 6); 
                float angle2 = (float) (phi + Math.PI / 6);

                float x3 = (float) (x2 - h * Math.cos(angle1));
                float x4 = (float) (x2 - h * Math.cos(angle2));
                float y3 = (float) (y2 -  h * Math.sin(angle1));
                float y4 = (float) (y2 -  h * Math.sin(angle2));

               c.drawLine(x1, y1,x2,y2 ,pnt);
               c.drawLine(x2, y2,x3,y3 ,pnt);
                c.drawLine(x2, y2,x4,y4 ,pnt);



                myimageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                i=1;
            }
            }

           }





}
```

and in my xml file where I get the error is :

> ```
> <ImageView class= "com.infy.DrawActivity$MyView"
>     android:id="@+id/myView"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_weight="1.01"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
> ```

and log cat is:

```
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/29 }} to activity {com.infy/com.infy.DrawActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.infy.DrawActivity$MyView
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.infy.DrawActivity$MyView
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.infy.DrawActivity.onActivityResult(DrawActivity.java:153)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
07-23 10:47:13.098: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infy.DrawActivity.myView  <--- everything allright within AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes,its something to do with inflating the myView class

Comment: It's an inner class right? try referencing it like so: `com.infy.DrawActivity$myView` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml

Comment: Use MyView  instead of "myView" & try again.

Comment: Make all constructrs public. change <ImageView class= to <view class=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an inner class of `DrawActivity` so you need to reference it in your XML like so:

```
<view class="com.infy.DrawActivity$myView" 
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.01"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

See here: [Error referencing an inner class View in layout/main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml)

Alternatively, move it to it's own class.

Comment: Hi , I am still getting an error though. I am getting a class cast exception. The logcat says can't cast widget. imageview to drawactivit$MyView.Could you help me with this .

Comment: Can you ask a new question with the latest code? It's quite confusing now and it will make it easier for people to help you with this specific problem. Strangely it's referencing `MyView` with a capital `m` but I don't see that anywhere in your code...

Comment: Hi,  I am not allowed to ask a new question. I have edited the entire question again. Can you please look into it

Answer (score 1):

Define your class as public static and add all necessary View constructors

```
public static class myView extends ImageView {
    myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs)
    }

    myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
```

And reference it like this

```
<view class="com.infy.DrawActivity$myView"
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.01"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Tip: according to Java conventions class names should start from upper-case letter.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

`myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) and myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`

In your custom ImageView.

Comment: You are correct. But this is not the main crash problem. It would appear after OP fixes ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Hi , you were right. But now I am getting a class cast exception. The logcat says can't cast widget. imageview to drawactivit$MyView.

Comment: The `class cast exception` is due to the fact you are using inner class for view. 
Make a separate class for your View either in the same file or other file and change path in `xml`.