# How to solve : Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-inflate, android-background

My app consist on moving a picture when the user speaks. I have done this, but  I have a problem while I try to set a image as background for my app. I am trying to do this using the xml file but I get the Error inflating class. Can anyone help me, please? 
Thanks in advance

Line 8 in xml class is:

```
<com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.DrawBalloon
        android:id="@+id/drawBalloon1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp" />
```

and the logcat said:

```
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prova1/com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.DrawBalloon
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.DrawBalloon
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.onCreate(MoveBalloon.java:95)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    ... 11 more
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.DrawBalloon
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:558)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
09-22 14:20:56.391: E/AndroidRuntime(20776):    ... 21 more
```

The class MoveBallon wherer I am trying to connnect with xml is this

```
package com.example.prova1;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MoveBalloon extends Activity {
 Bitmap balloon;
 DrawBalloon myView;
 float x,y,sensorX, sensorY;
 SensorManager sm;
 Microphone mic;



public class DrawBalloon extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

 SurfaceHolder ourHolder ;
 Thread ourThread = null;
 boolean isRunning=true;

 public DrawBalloon(Context context) {
 super(context);
 ourHolder= getHolder();
 }

 public DrawBalloon(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ourHolder= getHolder();
    }

 public void pause() {
  isRunning=false;
  while(true){
   try{
    ourThread.join();
   } catch (InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   break;
  }
  ourThread=null;
 }

 public void resume(){
  isRunning=true;
  ourThread = new Thread(this);
  ourThread.start();

 }
 @Override
 public void run (){
  while(isRunning){
   if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
    continue;
            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

   updateMic();
   canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
   canvas.drawBitmap(balloon, sensorX, sensorY,null);
   ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
  }
 }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 /*sm= (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
 if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size()!=0){
  Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(o);
  sm.registerListener(this,s ,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }*/
mic = new Microphone();
balloon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.images);
sensorX=150;
sensorY=350;
//x=y=sensorX=sensorY=0;
//myView= new DrawBalloon (this);
//myView.resume();
//setContentView(R.layout.move_balloon);
setContentView(R.layout.move_balloon);
}



/*@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 try {
  Thread.sleep(20);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 sensorX=event.values[0];
 sensorY=event.values[1];

}

*/
public void updateMic(){
int level = mic.getLevel();

 sensorY-=level;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


 finish();


    }


}
```

This is my new xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MoveBalloon"
        android:background="#00000000" >

    <view class="com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon$DrawBalloon" 

        android:id="@+id/drawBalloon1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use class attribite

see this [Error referencing an inner class View in layout/main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml)

Comment: I make this but an error ocurred and said:        Element type "com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I make this so i change the my xml file and it looks like I have posted above, but I still get this error:                                     RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prova1/com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon$DrawBalloon
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Comment: make your inner class static