# ClassCastException on custom Webview

Tags: android, classcastexception

In my onCreate, I have:

```
MyWebView webView = new MyWebView(this, null);
webView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.pdf);
```

The custom webview class inside the Deal class:

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

     Paint p = new Paint();

     public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

         super.onDraw(canvas);
         p.setColor (Color.RED);
         canvas.drawLine (20, 10, 300, 400, p);
     }
 }
```

The XML:

```
<im.magic.dealpdf.Deal.MyWebView
    android:id="@+id/pdf"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The error states it didn't find the class im.magic.dealpdf.Deal.MyWebView. Why is the error coming up? Changing the xml to im.magic.dealpdf.Deal results in `cannot be cast to android.view.View`

Update: I think I need to extend View in my Deal class. But it already extends Activity

Comment: try to clean and build your project again that might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use inner classes in such way, declare MyWebView as

```
public static class MyWebView extends WebView {
...
}
```

Otherwise it's not possible to create a MyWebView instance outside a Deal instance.
Inner classes can't be referenced in such way in the layout file, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100111/1122966) you have to wrote something like this:

```
<view class="im.magic.dealpdf.Deal@MyWebView" 
    android:id="@+id/pdf"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```