# Eclipse can't find extended View class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement a custom [Facebook Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/LoginButton/): it'll be exactly the same, save for the fact it'll have extra functionality after the user has logged in; I don't wish to change it's style or anything pertaining to how it looks/feels.

The button needs to be called explicitly in the xml file:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

I extended the [LoginButton](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/LoginButton/) class and added a single method (where I want my functionality to occur):

```
public class CustomFBButton extends LoginButton{

    public CustomFBButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void enablePublishActions(final Activity activity) {
                 //EXTRA FUNCTIONALITY
    }
}
```

Now, to my understanding, I should call my button as follows(and I'm doing it exactly like this):

```
<com.company.helpers.FacebookClass.CustomFBButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

`com.company.helpers` is the package where `FacebookClass` is located in.
`CustomFBButton` is a subclass within `FacebookClass`.

Am I calling it right? Apparently, Eclipse can't find the class: it appears to be looking for the class in another package.

```
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.product.main/com.company.product.settings.Settings}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.company.helpers.FacebookClass.CustomFBButton
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.company.helpers.FacebookClass.CustomFBButton
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:133)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at com.company.product.settings.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:34)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    ... 11 more
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.helpers.FacebookClass.CustomFBButton" on path: /data/app/com.company.product.main-2.apk
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-24 16:11:00.899: E/AndroidRuntime(28004):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2100111/3194316

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error referencing an inner class View in layout/main.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml)

Comment: Nope: tried it and I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: what did you try exactly?

Comment: Noticed I didn't do the '$' and retried it. Solved that error, but now I can't cast it to my class (I get ClassCastException error when I try to cast it in my Java code). Workaround?

Comment: Show us where you tried instantiating the button in your java code.  Should look something like `CustomFBButton button = (CustomFBButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);`

Comment: That is, literally, the exact same thing I have. And also, where I'm getting the error. Shouldn't I be able to cast it correctly, since the view is - to my understanding - instantiating that exact same view in the xml (via the class="" attribute)?

Comment: hmm maybe you should try printing what class the view is returning?
`(findViewById(R.id.login_button)).getClass.getCanonicalName();`

Comment: I'ts returning:  `android.view.View`