# android.view.inflate exception, Binary xml file line #28 Error inflating class com.xyz.featureTop

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-inflate

I am getting above error on loading my layout to activity. Please have a look in below code 
my xml layout file -

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <com.xyz.FeatureTop
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".35" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello Feature Top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.xyz.FeatureTop>

    <com.xyz.Middle
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".35" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello Feature Middle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.xyz.Middle>

    <com.xyz.FeatureBottom
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello Feature Bottom"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.xyz.FeatureBottom>
</LinearLayout>
```

and below is my classes -

```
public class Xyz extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class FeatureTop extends LinearLayout implements
        IndustryCollectionDetailsListener {

    public FeatureTop(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public FeatureTop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public FeatureTop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public void featureTopDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureTopDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureBottomDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureBottomDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void middleDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void middleDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

public class FeatureBottom extends LinearLayout implements
        IndustryCollectionDetailsListener {

    public FeatureBottom(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public FeatureBottom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public FeatureBottom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public void featureTopDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureTopDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureBottomDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureBottomDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void middleDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void middleDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public class Middle extends LinearLayout implements
        IndustryCollectionDetailsListener {

    public Middle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Middle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public Middle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public void featureTopDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureTopDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureBottomDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void featureBottomDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void middleDownloadSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void middleDownloadFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}
I don't know about this error. Is there any property i am missing in xml? I am new to android development
Thanks in advance.

Comment: -_- show stack trace and show line #28

Comment: in XML `com.xyz.Xyz.Middle` -> your packacke, dot, class, dot, inner class ?

Comment: Stack trace - 11-28 16:28:42.604: E/AndroidRuntime(6324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.xyz.FeatureTop and line 28 is <com.xyz.FeatureTop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<com.xyz.Middle
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".35" >
{...}
</com.xyz.Middle>
```

try this (this is  the syntax for inner classes) if your Xyz class in in package `com.xyz`:

```
<com.xyz.Xyz$Middle
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".35" >
{...}
</com.xyz.Middle>
```

And do the same for `com.xyz.FeatureBottom` and etc.

Comment: after putting $ sign it removes the inner class and make xyz as a property. <com.xyz
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            FeatureTop="" >       and i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that if i saperate the class then its working fine. But if its inner class its not working and giving me that error. Why its happening like that I don't know. does anyone know how can I do it with inner class?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here -
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml)

I put it in class property-

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".35" 
        class = "com.xyz.FeatureTop">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello Feature Top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
```